# Kohana Sessions Issue

Tags: php, session, kohana, kohana-3

Let me try to explain what I want to do here.  I am trying to re-write a pet project from Codeigniter 2.x to Kohana 3.2.x.

I have created a Site Template controller (below)

```
class Controller_Site_Template extends Controller_Template 
  {

      public $template      = 'templates/hero';

      /**
       * The before() method is called before your controller action.
       * In our template controller we override this method so that we can
       * set up default values. These variables are then available to our
       * controllers if they need to be modified.
       */
      public function before()
      {
          parent::before();

        if ($this->auto_render)
        {
            // Initialize empty values
            $this->template->title   = '';
            $this->template->content = '';
            $this->template->session = '';

            $this->template->styles = array();
            $this->template->footer_scripts = array();

          $session = Session::instance();
          $this->template->session = $session;

        }

      }

      /**
       * The after() method is called after your controller action.
       * In our template controller we override this method so that we can
       * make any last minute modifications to the template before anything
       * is rendered.
       */
      public function after()
      {
            if ($this->auto_render)
            {
                $styles = array(
                    'assets/css/style.css' => 'screen',);


                $footer_scripts = array(
                                    'assets/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js',
                    'assets/js/application.js',
                );

                $this->template->styles = array_merge( $this->template->styles, $styles );
                $this->template->footer_scripts = array_merge( $this->template->footer_scripts, $footer_scripts );
            }

            parent::after();
      }
```

After the login form is submitted I set the session data and I am able to retrieve the session data in the Controllers that extend the Controller_Site_Template but I am unable to retrieve the session data in any of the View files.

The only way I am able to get the session data in the view files is to pass the session data in each controller that extends the Template_Site_Template:

```
$this->template->content->set_global('session',$this->template->session->as_array());
```

Is there an easy way to establish and set the session in the template_controller that can be used in all of the controllers, modelc, views rather that using the set_global on each individual controller?

I don't know if I am explaining this well but I am used to the ease of Codeigniter's $this->session->userdata(); function that can be called in any controller, model, and view once it was set.

Thank you in advance for any input on what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set or bind global data to your views with the following

```
View::bind_global('session', $session);
View::set_global('session', $session);
```

If you plan to change any data further along the application logic, then use **bind**.

If no more changes to the data are required, use **set**.

Edit: oh, the above is just for views and you want it across the entire application.

Just use the Session::instance()->set() and Session::instance()->get() as required across your application rather then assigning it in your application controller.

Comment: I was just so used to Codeigniter and Kohana 3 is just a little more strict on the whole MVC.  Thanks Fady.